# My PHP form is sending random blank emails?

Tags: php, email

I have a application form on my website and when someone fills one out it works fine with all data properly sent over, however multiple times a day we are getting completely blank emails. (client is CONVINCED that its people filling out the form and its sending it blank randomly removing their information - i dont think thats possible)

Here are snippets of my code:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {  
if (trim($_POST['fname']) == "") {  
       $errors[] = "Please enter your first name";
    }
if (trim($_POST['lname']) == "") {  
       $errors[] = "Please enter your last name";
    }  
if (trim($_POST['address1']) == "") {  
       $errors[] = "Please enter your address";
    }  
if (trim($_POST['city']) == "") {  
       $errors[] = "Please enter your city";
    }  
if (trim($_POST['state']) == "") {  
       $errors[] = "Please enter your state";
    }  
if (trim($_POST['zip']) == "") {  
       $errors[] = "Please enter your zip code";
    }  
if (trim($_POST['email']) == "") {  
       $errors[] = "Please enter your email";
    }  
if (trim($_POST['phone']) == "") {  
       $errors[] = "Please enter your phone number";
    }  
if (trim($_POST['school']) == "") {  
       $errors[] = "Please enter your High School";
    }  
if (trim($_POST['school_study']) == "") {  
       $errors[] = "Please enter your course of study";
    }  
if (trim($_POST['school_years']) == "") {  
       $errors[] = "Please enter your school years completed";
    } 
if (trim($_POST['school_degree']) == "") {  
       $errors[] = "Please enter your diploma/degree";
    }
if (trim($_POST['employer1']) == "") {  
       $errors[] = "Please enter Employer #1";
    }
if (trim($_POST['employer1_telephone']) == "") {  
       $errors[] = "Please enter Employer #1 Telephone";
    }
if (trim($_POST['employer1_title']) == "") {  
       $errors[] = "Please enter Employer #1 Title";
    }
if (trim($_POST['employer1_supervisor']) == "") {  
       $errors[] = "Please enter Employer #1 Supervisor";
    }
if (trim($_POST['employer1_from']) == "") {  
       $errors[] = "Please enter Employer #1 Start Date";
    }
if (trim($_POST['employer1_to']) == "") {  
       $errors[] = "Please enter Employer #1 End Date";
    } 
if (trim($_POST['employer1_salary']) == "") {  
       $errors[] = "Please enter Employer #1 Salary";
    }
if (trim($_POST['employer1_duties']) == "") {  
       $errors[] = "Please enter Employer #1 Duties";
    }
if (trim($_POST['sig2']) == "") {  
       $errors[] = "Please complete the Signature Field";
    }
if (trim($_POST['date2']) == "") {  
       $errors[] = "Please complete the Date Field";
    }
    if(is_array($errors))
    {
        echo '<div class="error"><span>The following errors occurred:</span><ul>';
        while (list($key,$value) = each($errors))
            {

            echo '<li>'.$value.'</li><br />';
        }echo'</ul></div>';
    }
    else {

        require_once('recaptchalib.php');
        $privatekey = "(private key thing here not sure if that should be shared)";
        $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                    $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                    $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                    $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

                  if (!$resp->is_valid) {
                    // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
                    die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
                         "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
                  } else {
// convert the application to a pdf. not going to include all this jarble
// also insert the application into a database - not including

$mpdf=new mPDF(); 


$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);

$content = $mpdf->Output('', 'S');

$content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));

$eol = PHP_EOL;
$mailto = "$setting[apps_email]";

$from_name = 'Employment Application';
$from_mail = 'no-reply';
$replyto = 'no-reply';
$uid = md5(uniqid(time())); 
$subject = "".$row[fname]." ".$row[lname]." - ".$row1[position]."";
$filename = "".$row[fname]."".$row[lname]."-".$row[submitted].".pdf";


$header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">".$eol;
$header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto.$eol;
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"".$eol;
$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit".$eol;

$message .= "--".$uid.$eol;
$message .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n";
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
$message .= $eol."".$row[fname]." ".$row[lname]." has submitted an employment application for the ".$row1[position]." position. Please see the attached .pdf file to save and/or print the application.".$eol;

$message .= "--".$uid.$eol;
$message .= "Content-Type: application/pdf; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n";
$message .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";

$message .= "Content-Disposition: attachment".$eol.$eol;
$message .= $eol.$content;
$message .= "--".$uid."--".$eol;

$is_sent = @mail($mailto, $subject, $message, $header); 
                  }
}}
```

I feel like i've taken every measure against this with making sure it was submitted first, validating required fields, and i even threw on a stupid captcha that i hate doing

any idea why (i'm assuming crawlers) are sending blank emails?

Comment: Not sure if this would help, but how about instead of checking `is_array($errors)`, you declare `$errors = array();` at the top of the code and then below check `if(!empty($errors))`. That would prevent at least one notice error that you are not seeing.

Comment: ouch, learn how to write a loop and create a function

Comment: @Dagon thank you for the incredibly constructive feedback. totally helped me solve my problem

Comment: you don't think that would make debugging your problem easier? i sure do.

Comment: @Dagon i'm new at this, learning on the fly. I don't even know what you are addressing

Comment: so responding sarcastically to a suggestion you don't understand is your approach to getting 'free' help - best of luck with that.

Comment: thanks, hopefully someone is kind enough to actually help instead of smugly attacking my code

Comment: @user2391454 - this may be a dumb question, but what do you mean by completely blank emails? Do you mean that the email is being sent with absolutely nothing in it, so it's effectively 0-length?

Comment: @andrewsi it still has the content i have going into the subject etc. but anything that would be generated from the form is left out

Comment: @user2391454 - my feeling is that it's a bug in your form, in that case. You're checking that fields aren't blank, with the trim calls, and you have a captcha - a robot wouldn't be able to successfully submit with the captcha in place, and a spammer would be entering random data which would be entered into the fields. It's most odd - you say you're also writing to a database, so is there anything added there for emails that are coming through as blank?

Comment: @andrewsi the most confusing part is the blank emails are not being submitted to the database as blank applications. i have nothing that checks to make sure its not blank before adding it either

Comment: @user2391454 - so anything that gets passed the validation is added to the database and then emailed. Except that it's not being added to the database, but there's still an email going out?

Comment: @user2391454 - I still think it might be an issue in your code. Could the database insert be failing? Could you add the database code to the the question, and a little bit of the PDF generation?

Comment: @andrewsi right, with every single form being blank. which is what i dont understand since testing it myself i cannot get it to send without data in all the required fields

Comment: @user2391454 - your code does seem fine, which is why I'm wondering if the problem is in the parts you've missed out. What would happen if `Mr O'Brian` applied? Or if someone entered HTML markup in the fields? I admit, I'm not sure at all.

Comment: @user2391454 - Alternatively, if you want to be really sure - add a couple of extra lines of code, so that whenever a form is emailed, it emails you with the actual contents of $_POST. You'll see precisely what was entered, as well as when, so if there's a blank entry submitted, you'll see what caused it.

Comment: @andrewsi Every app that i've personally filled out with 'test test test test' etc has worked perfectly fine and we continually get apps with full filled out information daily.

Comment: @user2391454 - it's the people doing the unexpected you need to worry about. As I say - have it mail you the contents of $_POST when it's submitted, and compare those with the emails that they say are blank to see what the difference is between emails that work and ones that don't.

Comment: @user2391454 - no problem. Let me know if you can figure it out - it's intriguing!

Comment: @andrewsi so i got some blank ones overnight and the $_POST dump had all legit values so it must be something wrong with entering in the database, i've been looking in the wrong place the whole time

Comment: @user2391454 - you could post the database code as a separate question if you wanted more eyes to try and figure out what's going on.